# What is the full list of DFP Video replacement tokens/macros?

Tags: android, ios, google-dfp

A DFP Video pre-roll ad contains URL replacement tokens such as:

```
[referrer_url],[description_url],[timestamp]
```

Where can I find a full list of token values, that are replaced client side in the DFP SDK (iOS,Android) AND what they mean?

Here is an example of the tokens used as values for DFP query string parameters:

```
url=[referrer_url]&description_url=[description_url]&correlator=[timestamp]
```

DFP documents the [server side macros](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1242718?hl=en) however I can not find docs on the client side tokens

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1068325 which I got from https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1181016

Comment: @MorrisonChang nope, that just talks about the query string keys. I'm looking for a list and definition of supported tokens that can be used as values